# Django - How to convert URL template syntax to Django 1.5?

Tags: django, django-1.5

I was able to convert most {% url %} template syntaxes to Django 1.5.

But I'm not able to convert this kind of old url's to Django 1.5:

```
{% url monthly_archive date|date:'Y' date|date:'m' %}
```

This does not work:

```
{% url "monthly_archive date|date:'Y'" date|date:'m' %}
```

Any ideas?

Best Regards,

Comment: Does `{% url "monthly_archive" date|date:'Y' date|date:'m' %}` work?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you put the close quote there, after the first parameter? That makes no sense. It should go after the URL name, so that the thing quoted is just `"monthly_archive"`.